# QSystemTrayIcon activated signal: DoubleClick without Trigger

Tags: c++, qt

I want to show context menu on left click and run app on double click.
For this i have next code:

```
...
connect(this, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), this, SLOT(slotActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
...
void MyTray::slotActivated(ActivationReason reason)
{
    if(reason==QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick)
        startApp();
    else
        if(reason==QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger
           || reason==QSystemTrayIcon::MiddleClick)
                contextMenu()->popup(QCursor::pos());
}
```

It works, but for double click case i got two slot calls - one for Trigger and only then for DoubleClick. As result context menu shown and hidding in a moment.
Is there is a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using slotActivated, you need to handle the mouse events.

Whilst these aren't directly available in [QSystemTrayIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html), it does allow you to [install an event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) and handle the mouse events from there.

Comment: good idea, but i still hope that there is a more straightforward solution

Comment: Well, you could use a timer that waits a moment to see if it's actually a double-click ( [example here](http://pastebin.com/5JWykSgU) ), but the event filter is really the way to go and IMHO, rather straight forward too.

Comment: Also it is better to replace `300` by `QApplication::doubleClickInterval()` in this example from pastebin.

Comment: @Ilya, great idea, though that code is slightly flawed and the reason why I didn't inline it with the answer. I suspect it would be possible to confuse its state, which is why the event filter is the preferred (correct) method.

Comment: bad news for all who needs to support MacOS - this method not works on MacOS.